# what is the difference between "python -v" and "python -V" when run in ubuntu/trusty64?

Tags: python

I am trying to determine the python version but when I run the command python -V with a lower case "v" I see I was moved to the python prompt rather than just returning the python version with me. I tried finding the difference between the 2 but couldn't find anything helpful. Please advice as to what is the difference between the two.

Comment: What about `man python`

Answer (score 6):

From `man python`:

```
-v     Print a message each time a module is initialized, showing the place (filename or built-in module) from
              which it is loaded.  When given twice, print a message for each file that is checked for when searching
              for a module.  Also provides information on module cleanup at exit.

-V ,  -version
      Prints the Python version number of the executable and exits.
```

Long story short

1. `python -v`: when you execute `python -v` several `modules` will be loaded in anticipation of the work for which python is to do for you, `python` alone will get you the python prompt but will not show you the loaded modules and their file location, so `python` and `python -v` are in a way equivalent but the latter is more verbose as it shows what gets `loaded` and `unloaded` on `exit`. With this you can see what modules are available to you for work in python.
2. `python -V`: simply just prints the version number and exits with no python prompt.

Answer (score 1):

From `man python`:

```
   -v     Print  a  message each time a module is initialized, showing the
          place (filename or built-in module) from  which  it  is  loaded.
          When  given twice, print a message for each file that is checked
          for when searching for a module.  Also provides  information  on
          module cleanup at exit.
```

Cheers

Comment: search the man page using '/'

Comment: Doesn't answer what the difference is between -V and -v ;)